# Url Routing in ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net

I have created a project in Asp.Net and having following files Global.asax.cs and RouteConfig.cs. Now i am trying to manually give url for my pages like for my Index.aspx page i want to show only 'localhost/{something}/login' for this i did some following things but still it is showing 'localhost/{something}/Index.aspx' and one more thing i set it as my start page

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "Login", "~/Index.aspx");
    }
```

can anybody help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to your solution; the MapPageRoute method contains three parameters

1. routeName: the route name which you want to use internally within
   you code behind
2. routeUrl: this is URL which comes up in the
   browser address,
3. physicalFile: this is the location of your file

You have done right about the physicalFile but about the URL you are doing wrong so simply do as following:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "something/login", "~/Index.aspx");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes that was working fine. When I type url in browser (like localhost:/home/login). But I set my Index.aspx as start page and when I run my application at that time it shows Index.aspx, so how to resolve this.

Comment: That can't be avoided; as its in development it will come up this won't be a big deal in production so don't worry